# Is it possible to hide the namespace extension CLSID when creating junction point?

Tags: shell-extensions, junction

I've developed a namespace extension and added it under "my computer".
i'm playing with junction points and created one in the following manner:

1. created a folder named "MyExtension" under C:\
2. renamed the folder to "MyExtension.{CLSID}" where the CLSID belongs to my namespace extension.

after doing this, i manage to go through file explorer and surf my virtual folder and it's called "MyExtension" under C:\

so i have several issues that happen:

1. when i write "C:\MyExtension\MyFolder" via the address bar - everything works
2. when i try to use it via Run... - it doesn't work, i have to supply the CLSID in order for it to work "C:\MyExtension.{CLSID}\My folder"
3. also when listing the folder in the command line, i see the CLSID aswell

this is not a good experience for the user, is there a way to make the run work without the CLSID supplied?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don`t you want to use Desktop.ini file to define a folder as a junction point?

Comment: actually i've just discovered it and i'm trying it, is it possible to define a new drive as a junction point? (Z: for example?)

Comment: @DenisAnisimov it seems that after the first virtual item, i can't continue and use "\" in the start...Run, if i try: C:\MyExtension\Folder1\Folder2 it gives me "Location is not available" for C:\MyExtension\Folder1\

is there a workaround for this? is it known?

Comment: Command line knowns nothing about shell namespace extensions. It can access only to physical files. So you are going on a wrong way.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov but it works when i browse to C:\MyExtension\Folder1, also, i get autocomplete for all folders. Also if i add the file protocol (file://C:\MyExtension\Folder1\Folder2) it works well, and opens my virtual folder.

eventually, i want to try and give a good UX for the user to access my extension via Run - is there any other suggested way?
i've tried protocol (MyExtension://Folder1/Folder2) but it truncates some of the data, so i prefer not to go in this direction